# Spinner only retrieving the first item from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin, spinner

I have this on my WCF web service:

```
public List<string> GetLocation()
{
    InsertToFSRDataContext context = new InsertToFSRDataContext();

    var loc = from z in context.Parameters where z.ParamGroup == "LOCATION" orderby z.ParamValue ascending select z.ParamDesc;

    return loc.ToList<string>();
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
   BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttp();
   _client = new FSRServiceClient(binding, EndPoint);
   _client.GetLocationCompleted += ClientOnGetLocationCompleted;
   _client.GetLocationAsync();
}

private void ClientOnGetLocationCompleted(object sender, GetLocationCompletedEventArgs getLocationCompletedEventArgs)
{
   spinner1 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner1);
   List<string> list = new List<string>(getLocationCompletedEventArgs.Result);
   ArrayAdapter<string> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Drawable.spinner_item, list);
   spinner1.Adapter = adapter1;
}
```

On my android emulator, it only shows the first item on the spinner. What could be the problem here?

Comment: How many items are there when you are sending from WCF?

Comment: @AnupSharma 17 items only, so I have no idea why it isn't showing on the spinner

Comment: In the function `ClientOnGetLocationCompleted`, are you getting all 17 items in second line while debugging?

Comment: @AnupSharma So I run the app again then this error appeared: `Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=18; index=-1`

Comment: For some reason, I can run it just fine but only shows the first item on the spinner but sometimes I get that java.lang unhandled exception.

Comment: Hi, I still cant figure this out. Any idea?

Comment: From here everything looks okay. try adding another spinner or listview and set the adapter to see if it works.

Comment: @AnupSharma Already solved. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding `RunOnUiThread(()`. Didn't know it could be solved this easily.